# TF-slim layers count

Tags: tensorflow, neural-network, tf-slim

Would the code below represent one or two layers? I'm confused because isn't there also supposed to be an input layer in a neural net?

```python3
input_layer = slim.fully_connected(input, 6000, activation_fn=tf.nn.relu)
output = slim.fully_connected(input_layer, num_output)
```

Does that contain a hidden layer? I'm just trying to be able to visualize the net. Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[image]

You have a neural network with one hidden layer. In your code, `input` corresponds to the 'Input' layer in the above image. `input_layer` is what the image calls 'Hidden'. `output` is what the image calls 'Output'.

Remember that the "input layer" of a neural network isn't a traditional fully-connected layer since it's just raw data without an activation. It's a bit of a misnomer. Those neurons in the picture above in the input layer are not the same as the neurons in the hidden layer or output layer.

Comment: Thank you! That makes sense now! So, the code I have would represent that 3-layer neural network that you presented right?

Comment: Correct. The input size is the size of `input` in your code. The hidden layer is of size 6000. The output layer is of size `num_output`.

Answer (score 0):

From [tensorflow-slim](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/tree/master/tensorflow/contrib/slim):

> Furthermore, TF-Slim's slim.stack operator allows a caller to repeatedly apply the same operation with different arguments to create a stack or tower of layers. slim.stack also creates a new tf.variable_scope for each operation created. For example, a simple way to create a Multi-Layer Perceptron (MLP):

```
# Verbose way:
x = slim.fully_connected(x, 32, scope='fc/fc_1')
x = slim.fully_connected(x, 64, scope='fc/fc_2')
x = slim.fully_connected(x, 128, scope='fc/fc_3')

# Equivalent, TF-Slim way using slim.stack:
slim.stack(x, slim.fully_connected, [32, 64, 128], scope='fc')
```

So the network mentioned here is a `[32, 64,128]` network - a layer with a hidden size of 64.

Comment: Thank you for the comment! So, would the 32 neurons represent the input layer? Let's say we have an input with 1000 features. Doesn't that mean the input layer would have to condense the 1000 features into 32 neurons for the input layer? After that, would there be 32x64 weight connections from the input layer to the first hidden layer? Sorry for the questions, I'm just trying to understand this!

Comment: @dooder questions are always good! However I cannot answer this question, as I never work with Tensorflow.  So I don't know how the values condense. However, if you have layer of 32 neurons and a layer of 64 neurons, the amount of connections will indeed be 32 * 64.